# Adding button to layout and it will not show up

Tags: layout, aide

I'm adding a button to a linear layout and it does not show up. Main XML after adding button last button:

[image]

Preview button does not show:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use AIDE as well, it isn't quite reliable. Nor is its Design preview. So, basically, if your codes are correct just build the app and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are no place for the third button.

Reduce string  length in android:text of all buttons and check that button appears, or make linearlayout orientation vertical and check.

You must learn about "weight" attribute...